# Does android SmsManager show message is sent for numbers that are switched off?

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

I am trying to understand how `import android.telephony.SmsManager;` would know that an sms was successfully delivered.

I am using this code from the study guide

```
 protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      Log.i("Send SMS", "");

      String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

      try {
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "SMS failed, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Ordinarily,i know when i send an sms to a number that is switched off,i don't receive the delivery report to confirm that the message was received.Does `import android.telephony.SmsManager;` show the message was sent even if the number is switched off?.

Comment: By number off i mean that maybe your phone is out of charge and you cannot be reached when someone tries calling you.Sim cards need some charge you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
        package com.splash.smsManager;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.IntentFilter;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.telephony.SmsManager;
        import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class SendingSmsWithReport extends Activity {
            String sendingSmsStatus = "SEND";
            String deliverySmsStatus = "DELIVERED";
            PendingIntent send, delivered;
            BroadcastReceiver sendReceiver, deliveredRecevier;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
                send = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        new Intent(sendingSmsStatus), 0);
                delivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                        deliverySmsStatus), 0);
                Button sendSmsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                sendSmsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        SmsManager sms  = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "Hello Welcome to Android", send, delivered);
                        //5556 is Emulator Number.
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPause();
                unregisterReceiver(sendReceiver);
                unregisterReceiver(deliveredRecevier);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onResume();
                sendReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        switch(getResultCode())
                        {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Serice Found in your Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                };
                deliveredRecevier = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        switch(getResultCode())
                        {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Successfully Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms not Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                };
                registerReceiver(sendReceiver, new IntentFilter(sendingSmsStatus));
                registerReceiver(deliveredRecevier, new IntentFilter(deliverySmsStatus));
            }


        }
```

Comment: Do you have the other files that you could share or an apk you have compiled?.I have compile mine and its no good https://www.dropbox.com/s/ch72znu7y4xrtw2/sendsms-release.apk

Comment: I compiled it successfully but keeps crashing.

Comment: Dont have DropBox Account ! Testing in Device or Emulator ? .If u r testing in Emulator means send Exception available in LogCat. Because Application crashes  means there may be Exception or Error.

Comment: I Installed your apk file in My Emulator is works fine .Its Shows a Toast Message like "SMS Sent!"

Comment: I Installed your apk file in My Emulator is works fine .Its Shows a Toast Message like "SMS Sent!" You can also Manually check in DDMS/Emulator-Controll under Telephony Action provide some number in Incoming Number Edit Box and Sms Text in Message and Click Send Button the Sms will Available in Notification Tray...Happy Coding !

Comment: I finally got it to work but not without some few modifications.

Comment: Good . now your are taking full control of your Code !